# Configuring ppp to support IPv6

Tags: redhat, ipv6, pppoe

I need to setup a PPPoE server for IPv6 on Linux machine with RHEL 6.1. When I tried to start pppd, the output was the following:

```
~$ sudo pppd start
pppd:in file /etc/ppp/options:unrecognized option 'ipv6'
```

Here is the content of /etc/ppp/options file:

```
local
ipv6 ipv6cp-use-ipaddr
```

According to the [pppd man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pppd), the option 'ipv6' should be recognized. It puzzled me. I am not sure how to configure the PPPoE server to support IPv6 PPP connections now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't tried this in practise, but I read the manpage differently in this section:

```
+ipv6  Enable the IPv6CP and IPv6 protocols.

ipv6 <local_interface_identifier>,<remote_interface_identifier>
      Set  the  local  and/or  remote 64-bit interface identifier.
      Either one may be omitted. The identifier must be  specified
      in   standard   ascii   notation  of  IPv6  addresses  (e.g.
      ::dead:beef). If the ipv6cp-use-ipaddr option is given,  the
      local  identifier is the local IPv4 address (see above).  On
      systems which supports  a  unique  persistent  id,  such  as
      EUI-48    derived    from    the   Ethernet   MAC   address,
      ipv6cp-use-persistent option can be used to replace the ipv6
      <local>,<remote> option. Otherwise the identifier is random‐
      ized.
```

So I guess you want at least this in your option file:

```
+ipv6
ipv6
ipv6cp-use-ipaddr
```

and some IPv4 configuration (see the requirement for `ipv6cp-use-ipaddr` in the manpage excerpt above).

Comment: I have tried this in practice, and the `+ipv6` is what's working for me.

Comment: Oh,I solve the problem by build my own 'pppd'(with IPv6 Surpport options in Makefile.linux) instead of the default on Integrated in RHLE6.1. Make install,then restart pppoe-server.Then it works~ So,it just because it's not surpported in RHEL on the option of 'ipv6'.~ Thx all~

Comment: You don't need the `ipv6` option in there. That's only to manually set the IPv6 identifiers. It's better just to put either `ipv6cp-use-ipaddr` or `ipv6cp-use-persistent` without `ipv6`. In fact, pppd will fail unless you do.